# Form Wizard: error undefined variables

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to use the form wizard for using different template names but I get an error which I don't understand why cause it seem like it is just straight forward.

[using different template for each form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#using-a-different-template-for-each-form)

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

FORMS = [("customer", solution.forms.customerForm),  //got error undefined variables:solution 
     ("building", solution.forms.buildingForm)]

TEMPLATES = {"customer": "customer.html",
         "building": "building.html",
        }

class customerWizard(SessionWizardView):
def get_template_names(self):
    return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    do_something_with_the_form_data(form_list) //get error undefined variables
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/page-to-redirect-to-when-done/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from solution import forms *

FORMS = [
    ("customer", customerForm),  
    ("building", buildingForm)
]
```